# Pokemon starter decision helper

Tags: python, html, flask, routes

I am fairly new to python/flask and would like to create a flask web-application that serves  as a "personality test" which determines which of the original starter pokemon is the right for you based on the answers given.
There are 5 multiple choice questions.
I have declared global variables for every starter pokemon, that should be increased by 1 if the corresponding answer has been chosen.
After the 5th question this app should then display the right html file that simply tells the user which starter pokemon is the best fit for him/her. After submitting the fifth form, I always get the apology.html template, that should be rendered, when neither of the variables is bigger than the other two.

My instinct is that the variables do not properly get calculated, but I can't seem to figure out why.
I apologize if this seems very obvious, but I wasn't able to find anything like this in other questions asked and I am still very new to flask, with this being my first full application.

```
...
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

bs = 0 #global variable
sq = 0 #global variable
ch = 0 #global variable

@app.route("/question1/send", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def question1_send():
global bs, sq, ch
answer1 = request.form["answer1"]
if not answer1:
  return apology("You have to choose an answer!", 403)
else:
  if answer1 == "bs1":
    bs += 1
  elif answer1 == "sq1":
    sq=sq+1
  elif answer1 == "ch1":
    ch=ch+1
  return redirect("question2")

@app.route("/question1" ,methods=["GET", "POST"])
def question1():
if request.method == "GET":
  return render_template("question1.html")
return redirect ("question1/send")
```

...

```
@app.route("/question5/send", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def question5_send():
global bs, sq, ch
answer5 = request.form["answer5"]
if not answer5:
  return apology("You have to choose an answer!", 403)
else:
  if answer5 == "bs5":
    bs=bs+1
  elif answer5 == "sq5":
    sq=sq+1
  elif answer5 == "ch5":
    ch=ch+1
  return redirect("/results")

@app.route("/question5" ,methods=["GET", "POST"])
def question5():
if request.method == "GET":
  return render_template("question5.html")
return redirect ("question5/send")

@app.route("/results", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def starter_pokemon():
  if ch > bs and ch > sq:
    return render_template("charizard.html")
  elif bs > ch and bs > sq:
    return render_template("bulbasaur.html")
  elif sq > ch and sq > bs:
    return render_template("squirtle.html")
  else:
    return apology("Sorry something went wrong ", 403)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found():
    """Page not found."""
    return make_response(render_template("404.html"), 404)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flaskapp.run()
```

Here is the question5.html file that. It has radio buttons to choose an answer.
When you click the submit button it should redirect to /results which then renders the correct template showing which starter had the most answers chosen.
Maybe request.form.get("...") also does not retrieve the correct data

```
...

{% block main %}
<form id="question5" action="/question5/send" method="POST">
<h2>Which of these jobs would be your favourite</h2>
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer5" id="a5_bulbasaur" value="bs5">
  <label for="a5_bulbasaur">Gardener</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer5" id="a5_squirtle" value="sq5">
  <label for="a5_squirtle">Firefighter</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="answer5" id="a5_charmander" value="ch5">
  <label for="a5_charmander">fire breather</label>
  <br>
<button type="submit" name="b5">Next Question</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is one of the templates that "/results" should render:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Bulbasaur
{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
    <h1>It seems like bulbasaur is the perfect partner for you!</h1>
    <br>
    <img src="https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/001.png" alt="bulbasaur" width="" height="600">
    <br>
    <h2>You are a nature loving person, who cares about the people and animals around you that tries to find the balance in  everything you do.</h2>

 {% endblock %}
```

Like I said I hope this question is not too obvious that it makes it embarrassing to ask.
But I am stuck at this for 2 days and can't seem to figure it out by myself by reading flasks documentation.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi leonard.richertz, could you please provide the error message (it should got printed in the console of terminal)? If you can‘t find it, try to change the last line to „flaskapp.run(debug=True)“ to get the error message right in the browser. Thanks 

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I fixed one error by importing the correct helper function so I no longer get an error message after submitting the fifth question, but now I always get the apology.html template, that should be displayed, when neither of the variables bs, ch or sq are bigger than the other two.  It seems like the variables are not calculated correctly.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks @leonard.richertz, the first line of your question functions is always a return statement. This means it exits the function directly, and the code after the statement does not get executed. What you have to do is: put the statements after the return in extra functions with their own route, a.E. „/question1/send“. In your HTML files, change the link to submit your form to these routes. You have to do this for every question function, but then it should work.

Comment: Thanks @AXOME for your answer, I have tried that and edited my program and the question, so that you can see the changes I made. I still have some trouble to get it running properly. Do I have to call the question1_send() function again in the question1() function or does anyone see the mistake? I would be very grateful for any further assistance, since I can't seem to be able to figure it out by myself...

Comment: I found an issue in your template; your flask code looks for a value in the request.form variable. This variable is only available in POST requests, but the method of the request is not defined in the form tag in your templates. All you got to do is add method="POST" to the opening tag of your form (so it looks like this: <form id="question5" action="/question5/send" method="POST">). Oh, and the button to send the form does not actually send the form; remove the onclick attribute and set the type to „submit“ instead of „button“. You need to apply these things to all templates. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I am afraid I need your assistance once more XD. I have changed the opening form tag to <form id="question5" action="/question5/send" method="POST"> and the last line of the template to <button type="submit" name="b5">Next Question</button>, but now it seems that the variables that I declared in the application.py file to count the answers corresponding to each starter do not work how it is supposed to be. -i have changed the question to how the code looks now. Sorry for the amount of time that has passed, but I was very busy. I would really appreciate your help :)